# Message for current location permission

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I have an ionic2 application in which I need access to the current location of the mobile device. I'm using the cordova-plugin-geolocation to get the current location.

When I open the application, it pops up a message asking "Allow myAppName to access this device's location?". What I would like to do is to change the message of the pop up which I'm not sure how to do it...

The reason I want to change it is because the app was rejected for the apple store due to “Guideline 5.1.1 - Legal - Privacy - Data Collection and Storage”, which indicates that I did not specify why do I need the user’s location.

[[image: Permission to access current location [1]]

Answer (score 0):

The solution is described in [cordova-geolocation-plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation#ios-quirks). In sort you need to add in info.plist in ios the key NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription and the value for the reason.

In ionic this is done by adding in config.xml:

```
<edit-config target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
    <string>need location access to find things nearby</string>
</edit-config>
```